# Mobile Notification without internet (Local network only)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, push-notification, xamarin.android

I'm new in xamarin and i need to send and receive notification from a local server.

My project requires that no data go out of the building.
We now have a mobile application that handles many types of event in the building.
We wish to send the notification, from the server to the mobile application.

Can someone suggest me some articles to read on how to achieve this?

Note, the server has access to the internet, but not the router who serve business web apps and mobile applications.

Everything i find is cloud related. Maybe i don't use the rights keywords.

Thanks! :)

**Edit:**
The building have a wifi without internet to serve intern web apps.
We need to be able to receive notifications only on this wifi. We can't use Bluetooth because of the coverage distance.

Comment: Use Bluetooth perhaps

Comment: i forgot to say it must be able to be received anywhere in the building, within 100 feet ...

Comment: With the distance in mind, I think WLAN is your best choice.

Comment: Yes, but i don't know how to do it on the server side. Everything i find is related to cloud ....

Comment: Are you using static IPs for all the devices. If yes then its easy use networking concepts. broadcast messages to all connected devices or specific devices filtered by gateway. if you are using Dynamic IPs then its a little bit challenge, store connected devices information at server and then broadcast messages directly to client.

Comment: The suggested answers below are ok, but on a more practical level,  you are in a corporate network with restrictions. So most likely you have network engineers. Go and talk to them. They KNOW how YOUR network works and can easily suggest a solution without knowing how to implement it in code.  Network admins can be very helpful :)

Comment: @Benoit
Did you succeed with that, I also need mobile notification without internet. Can you help me how to make that.
I need
1. App periodically connects to a local server and asks if there are any pending notifications and throws a local notification if that is the case
2. Send notifications via a UDP connection while your app listens on an open port (this would allow you to either send direct notifications to the device ip or to all devices using a broadcast). Can you provide some source if you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since "real" Push Notifications need to be registered with Google Cloud Services or Apple Push Notification Services, you have to use local notifications.

These are being created from your app (example code below). However, you need some sort of service in your network, which will serve the notifications.

I see two possible solutions here:

1. Your app periodically connects to a local server and asks if there are any pending notifications and throws a local notification if that is the case
2. You send your notifications via a UDP connection while your app listens on an open port (this would allow you to either send direct notifications to the device ip or to all devices using a broadcast)

Unfortunately I don't have any example code for that at the moment, but I guess you should find plenty of examples on how to call an api or how to listen on a socket.

But as promised, here is the code to create local notifications from your app.

For creating local notifications, create an interface in your shared code (for example ILocalNotification.cs)

```
public interface ILocalNotification
{
    ShowNotification(string title, string message);
}
```

Then in your native implementations, add the following code:

**Android**

```
public class LocalNotification : ILocalNotification
{
    public void ShowNotification(string title, string message)
    {
        Context act = ((Activity)MainApplication.FormsContext);
        Intent intent = new Intent(act, typeof(MainActivity));

        // Create a PendingIntent; we're only using one PendingIntent (ID = 0):
        const int pendingIntentId = 0;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.GetActivity(act, pendingIntentId, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(act)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .SetContentTitle(title)
        .SetContentText(message)
        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);

        Notification notification = builder.Build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
            act.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
        const int notificationId = 0;
        notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);
    }
}
```

**iOS**

```
public class LocalNotification : ILocalNotification
{
    public void ShowNotification(string title, string message)
    {
        UILocalNotification notification = new UILocalNotification();
        notification.AlertAction = title;
        notification.AlertBody = message;
        notification.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduleLocalNotification(notification);
    }
}
```

Then call up the SendNotification method in your shared code by using a DependencyService.

Comment: Is there some restriction who don't allow the application to check each minutes for notifications? Do i need to create a service for that? (First time i play with background task). Tanks for the examples :)

Comment: I only have written a background service for location updates, which allows you to set parameters as minDistance, minTime and PowerRequirement, so i would have to research this as well. 

In the worst case, you could implement a timer which gets called every 10 seconds/minutes.

However, especially using udp broadcasts can be a bit tricky, since they are being blocked by android per default (but there are ways to circumvene that).

Comment: Thanks, i will search that way. I will accept your answer if nobody come with a better way ;-)

Comment: I have hacked together a quick proof of concept:
See [link](https://github.com/mmichelbb/UdpNotificationTest)

Answer (score 0):

All the cloud concepts are also applicable here.
If you know how to communicate with Web services you can easily communicate with local server.

All you need is HARD CODE your local server IP address into your mobile application. 
And let you application send or receive data from that server.
Simple!
But remember that your local server IP must be static (does not change) and firewall should allow communication on that specific protocol.